# How to prove partial ordering formally?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

The question is:

> The set $S$ is defined as
>
> - $\varnothing \in S$,
> - If $x \in S$, then also $\{x\} \cup x \in S$.
>
> Prove or disprove it is partial ordering.

So the set $S$ looks like $$\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\cup\varnothing, \{\{\varnothing\}\cup\varnothing\}\cup\{\varnothing\}\cup\varnothing,\cdots \},$$
right?

And I think it is **reflexive** because every set is a subset of itself, **antisymmetric** because two sets are subset of each other iff they are same, and **transitive** because $\subseteq$ is transitive. So it is partial ordering.

I don't know how to prove this formally, that is, use symbols and formal language to prove it.

Comment: The fact that $(S, \subseteq)$ is a partially ordered set is independent of what $S$ is, isn't it? You but need to prove three very elementary properties of set inclusion which are quite generally true.

Comment: The above does not *define* $S$ unless you also say that $S$ is the smallest sets with these properties. If you know ordinal numbers, both $\omega$ and $\omega+\omega$ could serve as $S$, but only $\omega$ is the smallest such set. It might be a partial order regardless whether it is the smallest.

Comment: A partial order on some set $S$ is a binary relation $R$ on $S$, i.e. $R \subseteq S \times S$. From your question, you have defined some set $S$ (though not uniquely, as @Mirko points out), but I'm not sure what your *relation* on $S$ is, and hence I don't know how to prove anything about it.